# CKFinder disable thumbnails and cache

Tags: ckfinder

I am trying to disable the creation of the thumbnails and cache directories with CKFinder 3.4.0. I would like the entire `.ckfinder` directory to not be made.

With thumbnails the documentation says to use this

```
$config['thumbnails'] = array(
    'enabled'      => false
);
```

Seems the thumbnails config is broke because it throws a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'disable' of undefined` whenever I put that in my `config.php`.

With cache there doesn't seem to be a disable. I can set the values to 0 but the `.ckfinder` directory is still made.

Answer (score 0):

i think config thumbnails is for external use. the one you talk about is for the internal api (CKFinder Internal Directory) and can not be set inactive.